# using pyrdown through function call

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-scaling

I was trying to use `pyrDown()`  to scale down the required image.For this I used a function call `void downscale(Mat *p,int *scale)`.I sent the ref to the image to the function.So, that after the function is done downsampling the image my original image will get changed since I sent the pointer.Image was getting scaled in the function call .But to my surprise there is no change in the image in main program.I do not understand where I went wrong.Can someone point out my mistake?
Here is my code

```css
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include<opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include<opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
#include<opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include<opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp>
#include<opencv2/features2d/features2d.hpp>
#include<opencv2/nonfree/nonfree.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;

void downscale(Mat *p,int scale)
{
 int s=scale;

 Mat ref=*p;
 
 imshow("received",ref);
 vector<int> param;
 param.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION) ;
 param.push_back(9);

 while(s){
 pyrDown(ref,ref,Size(),4);
 s--;
 }
 imshow("sending",ref);
}



int main()
{
 Mat ref,in,ref_out,in_out;
 int s=2;
 ref=imread("C:\\Users\\vamsidhar muthireddy\\Pictures\\Camera Roll\\WIN_20151003_18_47_55_Pro.jpg");

 cvtColor(ref,ref,CV_BGR2GRAY);

 

 imshow("original ref",ref);
 downscale(&ref,s);

 imshow("scaled ref",ref);

    waitKey();
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: use pass by reference...why do you need a pointer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change downscale to:

```
void downscale(Mat &ref,int scale)
{
int s=scale;

imshow("received",ref);
vector<int> param;
param.push_back(CV_IMWRITE_PNG_COMPRESSION) ;
param.push_back(9);

while(s){
pyrDown(ref,ref,Size(),4);
s--;
}
imshow("sending",ref);
```

and call it as:

```
downscale(ref,s);
```

Comment: Thanks,it worked.But ,Can you tell me what was wrong with my method?@basav

Comment: In my method,I changed `Mat ref=*p` to `Mat &ref=*p`.Instead of working directly with the original image,I was making a copy of it with the help of reference address.That was the reason for why I couldn't see the changes  in main program

Comment: mat ref=*p;   this makes a local copy and change wont be reflected

Comment: I just understood that by trial and error.Thanks for the help..!!